# How to remove hard spaces with Jsoup?

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm trying to remove hard spaces (from `&nbsp;` entities in the HTML). I can't remove it with `.trim()` or `.replace(" ", "")`, etc! I don't get it.

I even found on Stackoverflow to try with `\\u00a0` but didn't work neither.

I tried this (since `text()` returns actual hard space characters, [U+00A0](http://unicode.org/cldr/utility/character.jsp?a=00A0)):

```
System.out.println( "'"+fields.get(6).text().replace("\\u00a0", "")+"'" ); //'94,00 '
System.out.println( "'"+fields.get(6).text().replace(" ", "")+"'" ); //'94,00 '
System.out.println( "'"+fields.get(6).text().trim()+"'"); //'94,00 '
System.out.println( "'"+fields.get(6).html().replace("&nbsp;", "")+"'"); //'94,00' works
```

But I can't figure out why I can't remove the white space with `.text()`.

Comment: Does `.text().replace("&nbsp;", "")` work?

Comment: @Njol: Of course not, the markup won't appear in the text.

Comment: If you were to print the unicode character numbers of a string parsed by jSoup that has one, what number would you see?

Comment: It doesn't. When you get the text with .text() method Jsoup remove all the html stuff even the &nbsp. Maybe it changes the &nbsp; with  strange whitespace character?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your first attempt was *very nearly* it, you're quite right that Jsoup maps `&nbsp;` to U+00A0. You just don't want the double backslash in your string:

```
System.out.println( "'"+fields.get(6).text().replace("\u00a0", "")+"'" ); //'94,00'
// Just one ------------------------------------------^
```

`replace` doesn't use regular expressions, so you aren't trying to pass a literal backslash through to the regex level. You just want to specify character U+00A0 in the string.

Answer (score 8):

The question has been edited to reflect the true problem.

New answer;
The hardspace, ie. entity   (Unicode character NO-BREAK SPACE U+00A0 ) can in Java be represented by the character `\u00a0,` thus code becomes, where `str` is the string gotten from the `text()` method

```
str.replaceAll ("\u00a0", "");
```

Old answer;
Using the JSoup library,

```
import org.jsoup.parser.Parser;

String str1 = Parser.unescapeEntities("last week,&nbsp;Ovokerie Ogbeta", false);
String str2 = Parser.unescapeEntities("Entered&nbsp;&raquo; Here", false);
System.out.println(str1 + " " + str2);
```

Prints out:

```
last week, Ovokerie Ogbeta Entered » Here
```

Comment: Came across the same problem, this should be the accepted answer.

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP's question at all. He/she asked how to remove the hard space in the string. This doesn't. If you look in `str1` and `str2`, you'll see that they still have hard spaces (U+00A0) in them. This might be a useful answer to a *different* question, but not this one.

Comment: Sometimes people hit a page via Google and find an answer. Hence the 7 upvotes for a "non answer".

Comment: @NatanCox - So we should just post unrelated information to questions? That's not a recipe for a successful reference site. Better to post a relevant question and then answer it.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder the OP didn't ask "how to remove hard spaces with Jsoup?"....but asked "how to remove &nbsp; with Jsoup?"......for poorly formated document,  this answer will be useful....."remove" can mean "correctly format it" to some people.

Comment: @OvokerieOgbeta - I disagree. If you read the question, including its code, it's clearly about removing hardspaces, not unescaping entities (which `text` does, no need for `unescapeEntities`, and which the OP used in their question).

Comment: @T.J then the title (which search engine gives a higher priority to) is a little misleading for those who might come here and expect a formatting solution.

Comment: @OvokerieOgbeta - You're right, the title didn't accurately reflect the question. I've fixed that.

Comment: Hey, thanks man, this helped me find a solution to my problem, but more importantly helped me understand what's going on. Thanks, keep it up!