# Selecting 1MYR = 15.55 INR using Jsoup

Tags: html, jsoup

Please help me to select 1MYR = 15.55 INR using Jsoup.

```
<div style="position:relative;width:995px;height:25px;overflow:hidden">
   <div style="position:absolute;width:995px;height:25px;background-color:#ffffff" onmouseover="copyspeed=pausespeed" onmouseout="copyspeed=marqueespeed">
      <div id="iemarquee" style="position: absolute; left: 1359px; top: 3px; display: inline;">
         <div class="LBLBlack11">
           <b><font size="2">1 MYR = <font color="red">18.52 BDT</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/Bangladesh.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">15.55 INR</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/India.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">3,185.11 IDR</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/Indonesia.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">304.00 MMK</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/myanmar.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">24.95 NPR</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/Nepal.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">24.65 PKR</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/PAKISTAN.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">11.10 PHP</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/Philippines.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">0.32 SGD</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/Singapore.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">33.40 LKR</font>&nbsp;
            <img src="images/countryImages/SriLanka.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
           </b>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div id="iemarquee2" style="position: absolute; left: -307px; top: 3px; display: inline;">
         <div class="LBLBlack11">
          <b><font size="2">1 MYR = <font color="red">18.52 BDT</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/Bangladesh.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">15.55 INR</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/India.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">3,185.11 IDR</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/Indonesia.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">304.00 MMK</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/myanmar.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">24.95 NPR</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/Nepal.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">24.65 PKR</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/PAKISTAN.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">11.10 PHP</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/Philippines.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">0.32 SGD</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/Singapore.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1 MYR = <font color="red">33.40 LKR</font>&nbsp;
           <img src="images/countryImages/SriLanka.png" width="16" height="11">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font>
         </b>
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you did not show or explain what you have tried. This looks a lot like: "Here is my problem, now solve it for me!"

Comment: You can look for the image name ex.:Bangladesh.png

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a simple select:

```
String yourHtml = "...";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(yourHtml);
Element parent = document.select(".LBLBlack11 > b > font").first();
List<Node> nodes = parent.childNodes();
Node node4 = nodes.get(4);
Node node5 = nodes.get(5);
String result = "";
if(node4 instanceof TextNode){
    result += ((TextNode) node4).text().replace("\u00a0", ""); //Remove spaces
}

if(node5 instanceof Element){
    result += ((Element) node5).text();
}
System.out.println("Result: " + result);
```

To remove spaces I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21138099/1992780).